# JSF <ui:composition> is not working on destination page

Tags: jsf, navigation, richfaces

I am making a simple JSF application which is uses templating  It's very basic stuff but taking a lot of time to find the fix.
Issue is, I am having index.jsp which just forwards the request to startPage.xhtml. startPage.xhtml uses main.xhtml for templating. Till here everything is ok. But there is a anchor link of startPage.xhtml which leads the control to expression/expression.html. When I click on that link browser is not rendering my header and footer (part of main.xhtml template). IE consider expression/expression.xhtml a file and open it with open/save dialogue.

Index.jsp

```
<html>
 <body>
  <jsp:forward page="startPage.jsf" />
 </body>
</html>
```

main.xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />

<title>X</title>
<link
    href="css/styles.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style>
        .rich-table-headercell {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .rich-table-cell {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body
    style="bgcolor: #FFFFFF; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 20;">
    <!-- Start Header -->
    <h:form id="mainForm">

        <ui:include src="../includes/header.xhtml"/>

        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">
                    <table style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #E9ECEF; " width="100%" height="20px">
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap="nowrap"><img
                                src="images/spacer.gif"
                                width="18" height="1" border="0" alt="" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="globalNavGrey" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                                <h:outputText value="Help" /> <rich:spacer width="10" />                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
    <!-- main content area -->

    <table align="left">
        <tr>
            <td><img
                src="images/spacer.gif"
                width="5" height="1" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <!-- Body starts -->
                <ui:insert name="body">
                </ui:insert>
                <!-- Body ends -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

startPage.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd"
    template="/includes/main.xhtml">
<style>
    .cellBackground {
        background-color:yellow;
    }
</style>
    <ui:param name="subTitle" value="Understanding Disease Informatics System" />
    <ui:define name="body">
        <div
            style="margin-left: 30px; top: 120px; width: 800px; margin-bottom: 50px;"
            class="mainscreen">
            <br/> <b><font size="+1" color="003366">
X </font> </b><br/> <br/> This page is the entry point for X 
            developers development is organized into these subsystems:

            <p></p>
        <center>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="25">
                <tr>
                  <td class="cellBackground" title="Enabled" >
                    <a href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/expression/expression.xhtml" style="font-size:20px;"> Expression Subsystem</a>
                  </td>
                  <td title="Disable" style="font-size:20px;" >Pathways</td>                  
                </tr>                               
            </table>
        </center>
            <hr></hr>
            <font size="+1">
                <a href="contact">Contacts</a>
                <hr></hr>
            </font>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

expression.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd">

<ui:composition template="main.xhtml">
<ui:param name="subTitle" value="Expression Data" />
    <ui:define name="body">
        Expression page!
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

NOTE: As all the links on page are static so I am not using any managed bean.

Comment: Why do you have the html tags in the expression.xhtml page when they are part of the template? You didn't have them in the startPage.xhtml

Comment: I was trying different combinations. Initially I was not having <html> tag. Than I though may be that will solve, but.. didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the anchor tag with <h:link value="expression.xhtml">?

Comment: Oh no, i didn't try it. I will try it now.

Comment: Aah! I am using Richfaces 3.3.3, so <h:link> doesn't work with this version :( Any other suggestion?

Comment: Looks like you are importing the xmlns:h namespace, which is the jsf core taglib, so it should work. What error are you getting? You are also using h:output text which is in the same taglib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <jsp:forward page="startPage.jsf" />
> ```

Your `index.jsp` suggests that the `FacesServlet` is in `web.xml` mapped on an `<url-pattern>` of `*.jsf`.

However,

> ```
> <a href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/expression/expression.xhtml" style="font-size:20px;"> Expression Subsystem</a>
> ```

your `startPage.xhtml` has a link to `expression.xhtml` instead of `expression.jsf`. IE is retrieving the raw and unparsed JSF source code instead of its generated HTML. Whenever IE retrieves an `application/xhtml+xml` file, it doesn't know what to do with it, so it asks to download it.

You need to fix the link to match the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml`.

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/expression/expression.jsf" style="font-size:20px;"> Expression Subsystem</a>
```

*(note that I also simplified the context path retrieval)*

Alternatively, you can also just change the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` to `*.xhtml`. This way you can get rid of the ugly `index.jsp` altogether and set your `<welcome-file>` to `startPage.xhtml` and use URLs/links ending in `.xhtml` all the time.

Comment: I was suspecting that as the issue, but when I tried it I made a type of .jfs and it didn't worked. Then I posted question on SO. Thanks a lot. Definitively  I am gonna change web.xml to get rid of my idex.jsp.